# Laravel 5.8 with Heroku on deployment, Error : FORBIDDEN

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, deployment

After successfully deploying my laravel app on Heroku, I'm getting an error 'You don't have permission to access this resource' on accessing the app.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file called "Procfile" in your laravel root and write "web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/" in it then push, that fixed it for me, hope this helps.